# Get only one word from line

Tags: string, python-2.7, file

How can I take only one word from a line in file and save it in some string variable?
For example my file has line "this, line, is, super" and I want to save only first word ("this") in variable word. I tried to read it character by character until I got on "," but I when I check it I got an error "Argument of type 'int' is not iterable". How can I make this?

```
line = file.readline() # reading "this, line, is, super"
    if "," in len(line): # checking, if it contains ','
        for i in line:
            if "," not in line[i]: # while character is not ',' -> this is where I get error
                word += line[i] # add it to my string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, you are on the right track but there are a few things wrong that you can decipher if you always consider what data type is being stored where. For instance, your conditional 'if "," in len(line)' doesn't make sense, because it translates to 'if "," in 21'. Secondly, you iterate over each character in line, but your value for i is not what you think. You want the index of the character at that point in your for loop, to check if "," is there, but line[i] is not something like line[0], as you would imagine, it is actually line['t']. It is easy to assume that i is always an integer or index in your string, but what you want is a range of integer values, equal to the length of the line, to iterate through, and to find the associated character at each index. I have reformatted your code to work the way you intended, returning word = "this", with these clarifications in mind. I hope you find this instructional (there are shorter ways and built-in methods to do this, but understanding indices is crucial in programming). Assuming line is the string "this, line, is, super":

```
if "," in line: # checking that the string, not the number 21, has a comma
    for i in range(0, len(line)): # for each character in the range 0 -> 21
        if line[i] != ",": # e.g. if line[0] does not equal comma
            word += line[i] # add character to your string
        else:
            break # break out of loop when encounter first comma, thus storing only first word
```

Comment: Thank you for your explain my errors. :) And thank you more for adjusting your solution to my idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, using `split()`:

```
line = file.readline()
if "," in line:
    split_line = line.split(",")
    first_word = split_line[0]
    print(first_word)
```

`split()` will create a list where each element is, in your case, a word. Commas will not be included.

Comment: Thank you. :) Your solution is very neat and probably I will use your idea in the future. If I had ability to choose two best answers surely I would pick yours also. But I needed to choose one and in this very case I valuable more good explanation than elegant method.